# Multiple threads, each with different proxy settings

Tags: python, multithreading, proxy, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Is it possible to run multiple simultaneous thread with different proxy settings. Would calling this in the thread be ok:

```
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': http_proxy})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

If you called that same code in a function called from the thread would that be ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call those in a thread, but their behaviour would affect all threads, so you wouldn't get the result you want.

However, if you use `opener.urlopen(...)` instead of `urllib.request.install_opener(opener)` and `urllib.request.urlopen(...)`, it should work fine, with or without threads.